# How to reset password on remote windows server desktop machine?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, change-password

How to change password on remote Windows Server desktop? Usually I'll try <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> to change my password. But, if I do that on my system, my current system only goes to that screen, not my remote system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>INSERT</kbd> instead of <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>DELETE</kbd>. It should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a remote desktop application. You could use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>END</kbd>. Another option is to use the desktop app: "On-screen Keyboard" inside your virtual machine and click together <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DELETE</kbd>. As mentioned before <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>INSERT</kbd> works on some machines, but not on Windows 8.1 of Windows Server 2012 R2 machines. Typically, one of the three mentioned options works.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> it will show you change password option on your remote desktop.